# Help with Ruby Koans #6 - What exception has been caught?

Tags: ruby, exception

I'm trying to learn Ruby through Koans but I'm stuck on the 6th step.

Here's the code:

```
def test_you_dont_get_null_pointer_errors_when_calling_methods_on_nil  
  # What happens when you call a method that doesn't exist.    
  # The following begin/rescue/end code block captures the exception and  
  # make some assertions about it.  

  begin
    nil.some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about
  rescue Exception => ex
    # What exception has been caught?
    assert_equal __, ex.class

    # What message was attached to the exception?
    # (HINT: replace __ with part of the error message.)
    assert_match(/__/, ex.message)
  end
end
```

I know I'm supposed to replace the __ with something to do with the error message "NoMethodError" but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is the error message that I get when I run the "path_to_enlightenment.rb":

```
The answers you seek...
  <"FILL ME IN"> expected but was  <NoMethodError>.
```

I would really appreciate some guidance with this - it's driving me insane! I would love to know the answer and a possible explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer here is "NoMethodError"

you need the items on either side of the , to be equal, therefore making them both ex.class will do that.

Then you'll need to go on to /__/ Below.

Comment: Isn't that kind of cheating? Making a test pass by simply doing a 1 == 1 isn't valid, I would think. I'm trying to answer this one too

Comment: No, its asking you what error you're going to get for using a method an object doesn't know about. And because assert equal is all about making 1 == 1. NoMethodError must equal NoMethodError.

Answer (score 4):

I had to put the assert_equal statement into parens to get this one to pass. Must be a bug.

```
  def test_you_dont_get_null_pointer_errors_when_calling_methods_on_nil
    # What happens when you call a method that doesn't exist.  The
    # following begin/rescue/end code block captures the exception and
    # make some assertions about it.
    begin
      nil.some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about
    rescue Exception => ex
      # What exception has been caught?
      assert_equal(NoMethodError, ex.class)

      # What message was attached to the exception?
      # (HINT: replace __ with part of the error message.)
      assert_match("undefined method", ex.message)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to substitute __ with the actual

```
assert_equal NoMethodError, ex.class
```

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this one. I have been focused on one line at a time, but this method includes two items to be changed, one in row 16, one in row 20. Both are required to pass the lesson.

16: `assert_equal NoMethodError, ex.class`

20: `assert_match(/*some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about*/, ex.message)`

Hope that helps someone else who gets stuck!

Answer (score 1):

Carlo Ledesma has the correct answer. ( assert_equal NoMethodError, ex.class )
Don't know why Elliot's answer is top rated if someone asks you to solve equation,
`2x + 2 = 10`, you don't answer `2x + 2 = 2x + 2`. Mathematically you'd be correct, but it's not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For line 20 I used this: `assert_match(/some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about/, ex.message)` I don't know what those "/" characters are for. I'll have to research it, but that worked.

I think the trick was that the 'some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about was in single quotes in the message, so it was looking for that.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really answer the Q, can you please edit your answer to better reflect an actual answer to the Q instead of commentary? Otherwise post a comment (when you have the privileges to do so).

Answer (score 0):

I'm only on Koen 83, but in most of the Koens you can find the "answer" in the section appropriately titled "`The answers you seek...`" immediately after "`<"FILL ME IN"> expected but was`".  Every now and then I've broken the RubyKoan framework and I'll get this oldie ascii graphic (I'm not sure if it's supposed to be cupped hands or a tree, but hopefully you know it when you see it); in these cases the error message below the ascii graphic has been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

when you fill in the NoMethodError, you also need to fill in the error message (something to the effect of "undefined method 'some_methd..") you have to replace all the /__/ with your term not just the underscores

Answer (score 0):

If you remove quotes you can add a bit of the error message

```
assert_match(/undefined method/, ex.message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to answer it consecutively, which means starting from line `16`, then go to the line `20`.

line `16` => since `assert_equal` want 1 = 1, we need to look at `__` which is `nil.some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about` to be same to `ex.class`. As the Error says ;

```
Expected "FILL ME IN" to equal NoMethodError
```

We can see that the class itself is a "nil method that doesn't exist", which means it doesn't return anything. So no point to get errors. But in Ruby, we have a specific error for that, `NoMethodError`. The solution is;

```
assert_equal NoMethodError, ex.class
```

line `20` => logically, if we get an `Error`, we want a unique message for that. The answer itself is already given;

```
Expected "undefined method `some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about' for nil:NilClass" to match /__/
```

Just replace that message into `/__/`.
There have two answers here;

```
1)
assert_match(/undefined method/, ex.message)

2
assert_match(/some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about/, ex.message)
```

Enjoy ;p

Answer (score 0):

So this is a bit confusing but is actually the basics of how koans work - while filling in `NoMethodError` is the valid solution here so this becomes `assert_equal NoMethodError, ex.class` - it won't "solve" this specific koans as the function has another point to fix (line 20) - only solving both of those will result in a successful koan #6